# Joomla: Sub Menu Disappearing

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I have a Joomla install that is using Virtuemart for the shopping cart.

I have noticed as I go through my cart that I am loosing the sub menu and it seems to me that this is happening when I finally access the cart.

For example I see the submenu fine on this page

`index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=11&Itemid=15` but I think this is still running off the below code.

Once I click a dropdown menu link and get taken to

```
index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=18&Itemid=8
```

I loose the sub menu

**Does anyone know what document I edit to enable me to carry the sub menu into Virtuemart?**

**Code:**

```
<div id="sidebar"> 
        <h2>Products</h2>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="leftMenu"/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to enable that menu item to appear on the virtumart menu item.  VM uses a single menu id throughout the entire purchase/checkout process.  You'll notice that the Itemid in the url will remain the same all the way through, so any menu items that you want on any aspect of the checkout, will be visible from the beginning to the end.